# Why is access through the application to folder denied when application run after its installation?

Tags: c#, installshield

In use InstallShield 2015 Express for creating distributive of my application. I have a folder in my application. Lets call it "Repository". When I run the application after its installation on my computer I found that access to "Repository" folder is denyed for me. When I prepared the distributive in InstallShield I set "Require Administrative Privileges" option to YES. When I run installation of my application, I run it under administrative privileges. But when I run the installed application I have (when trying to access to "Repository" folder in application) SecurityException with message that access to "Repository" folder is denyed. Why access through the application to this folder is denyed for me after installation of application? How to correct this error to get access?

Comment: Are you reading or writing to that folder? Maybe it would help to show the relevant code snippet. Normally you need administrative privileges to _write_ to subfolders of the "Programs" folder. Therefor your application's data should be in some AppData folder. But if you're only reading (as the name "Repository" suggests) I guess it should work.

Comment: It can be, that the installation process creates this directory with the default user (and creator) as administrator and without access for other users. Check the access rights for the folder. But when the folder is in "Program Files" directory, then this is a standard behaviour. No data should be written by the application to this directory.

Comment: I should not only read but also write to "Repository" folder. So when I do the distributive then I must put "Repository" folder into "AppData" folder and it solves the problem?

Comment: Or during the installation some "AppData" folder containing "Repository" folder should be created outside of "Program Files" folder?

Comment: Giving access rights to the folder solves the problem.